# Find the number of possible values of $x+y+z$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Find the number of possible values $x+y+z$ if $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$ and $$x^4+4y^4+16z^4+64=32\cdot x\cdot y\cdot z$$

By applying Arithmetic-Geometric mean ineuality I got, $$x^4+4y^4+16z^4+64\ge32\cdot x\cdot y\cdot z$$
I don't know when the inequality holds.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what is necessary the the AM/GM to be an equality?

Comment: The equality occurs when all the elements are equal. $x^4=4y^4=16z^4=64$

Comment: @Andrei got it.